# amazon sesを用いたメール送信にDMARC認証を追加するには？

Tags: mail, amazon-ses

登録したメールアドレスからamazon sesを経由して複数のメールアドレスにメールを送信するメール配信システムを作成しているのですが、このメールがDMARC認証をパスする様にするにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか？

現状、SPFとDKIMはパスしているのですが、amazon ses側のドメインが認証されているので、送信元のメールドメインを認証させたいです。

Answer (score 0):

DMARCは、大雑把に説明すると「SPFやDKIMの検証に失敗したメールをどのように扱えばいいか」を宣言するもので、送信プロセス時に送信者側が参照するのではなく、受信側が参照する情報となっています。

そのため、基本的には「SPF,DKIMにパスしなかったメールの扱いをポリシーとして設計」した後に「自身のネームサーバー上にDMARC情報をDNSレコードとして登録」するだけで良いです。

`example.com`を対象とした場合：

- あらかじめポリシーを検討・設計する。（どのような構成にすればよいかは人それぞれなので、参考情報を確認しつつ自身で決定してください）
- `_dmarc.example.com`にポリシーを記載したTXTレコードを登録する。

### 参考情報

- [Googleが公開しているDMARCレコード追加のガイド](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466563?hl=ja)
- [RFC7489(DMARCに関するもの)の日本語対訳ページ](https://tex2e.github.io/rfc-translater/html/rfc7489.html)